# Windows Explorer freezes when dragging files over mapped network drives

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, freeze

As the title says whenever I drag a file over a disconnected mapped network drive Windows Explorer freezes.

After a minute it unfreezes again. Is there any way to fix this behaviour?

It looks like this when it freezes
[image]

Comment: Does it always happen, or only if you havn't touched the network drive for a while?  Note the red "x", this means it's currently disconnected, perhaps due to being idle. When you roll over it, you're waiting for the connection to be re-established.  If we can establish if it's due to idle, that idle time can be adjusted.

Comment: As it turns out I can't actually connect to this drive right now. It looks like when I drag files past it tries to connect to it and then freezes. I get the feeling that this is a bug in how windows handles network drives.

Comment: This is a sucky problem with Windows that has existed since windows XP! I really wish someone had a real solution to this!

Comment: Is there any way to remove mapped network drives from navigation pane?

Comment: and now 2022 , 7 years already, microsoft  has not been able to fix this bug. what a ....

Comment: It's been almost 10 years later and proof that Microsoft has no intention to listen to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To minimize traffic, Windows doesn't re-establish an idle/disconnected mapped drive connection until you go to use it.

Dragging a file over it in Explorer is enough for the OS to consider that you're trying to use it.

Similarly (haven't actually tested just now, but based on memory), if you have a hard drive that's sitting idle and had been spun down, and you dragged a file over it's letter in Explorer, it'd spin up, and Explorer would freeze for a bit until it heard back from the drive (or gave up waiting for it).

Comment: It's totally a bug :( Thanks anyway. Marking as Accepted

Comment: It's not a bug, it's the way Windows behaves by default... there is a sane reason why it's defaulted to operate in this manner, however I can't recall the exact wording & do not wish to paraphrase inaccurately. This is a feature that can be disabled, but do not recall how; there is a network setting somewhere that will disable Windows attempting to check if a mapped drive has a live connection or when a file drags over it, however I can't recall what it was I had to set to prevent it from doing so. While this doesn't provide much help, I at least wanted to share that it is possible to disable.

Comment: The bug's still there even on W10 and it's so annoying

Comment: @JW0914 It absolutely is a bug. Windows Explorer could do whatever it's doing in a background thread and not lock up the UI.

Comment: @Tibi A bug would signify something is wrong in the code and it's not... this is the expected behavior of Windows Explorer.  I can't provide a technical explanation but did provide a general one in my prior comment.  If you wish to understand the technical reasons why this occurs, researching how and why Windows Explorer handles network shares would be a good place to start.

Comment: It is a bug. If the user is dragging a file to another window and has _no intention_ of accessing the network drive, locking up like that is simply obnoxious.

Comment: While I agree it can be annoying (tho I haven't run into it in years), this answer is already 6 years old, and Windows has worked like this even longer, so debating if it's 'bug' or not, especially on here, is pretty pointless. Instead, perhaps [report your suggestion to Microsoft](https://superuser.com/a/1361684/23133). :)

Comment: This is a bug.  I run into this in 2022.

Answer (score 4):

Answer:

1. Vote on this bug: https://aka.ms/AA2pzti
2. This MS support conversation suggests checking your hover response time (mine is the default and I still have the problem): https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/windows-explorer-freezes-for-a-few-seconds/612d7e98-ee13-440d-969e-d6a72c67ead8

Quote from LuckySoul777:

> I know this is an old thread, but I stumbled over it when I was
> looking for a solution.  Since I have found one now, here it is.
> https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1884-mouse-hover-time-change.html
>
> Basically the "MouseHoverTime" value under HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control
> Panel/Mouse in the registry has been reduced to a ridiculously low
> value.  Who did it?  I don't know.  In my case, it was 8 (ms)!  By
> changing it back to the default value of 400, my problem is solved.
> Hope this is useful for everyone.