# How to remove mapped network drives/locations from Windows explorer navigation pane?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I need to remove all mapped network locations from navigation pane and only from the navigation pane for a very specific reason which is [mentioned in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/793236/windows-explorer-freezes-when-dragging-files-over-mapped-network-drives).

[image]

This seems like the only way to avoid that specific issue mentioned in that question. I've been dealing with this freezing issue since Windows 7.

Comment: See this https://winaero.com/blog/backup-restore-network-shares-windows-10/   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/125996/saving-and-restoring-existing-windows-shares

Answer (score 0):

regedit
section `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Policies/Microsoft/Windows/Explorer`

You may not have the last subkey, if so, you need to add it manually from the editor’s context menu. Regardless of the bit depth of your system, create a 32-bit DWORD parameter with the name `NoRemoteDestinations` and set its value to 1. Network locations will be hidden from the jump list after rebooting Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks for responding but this pretty much did nothing. Icons are still there.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to hide the mapped network shares is not to have any, using
alternate methods for addressing the shared data:

- Refer to the shares always by name and without mapping :
  `\\server\shareddata\`
- Create a Junction folder, or Symbolic link, to make the share appear
  as a sub-folder:

  ```
  mklink /d "c:\my_shares\network_share" "\\server\shared_data\"
  ```

---

To hide the Network icon and Network locations in Windows Explorer,
use the following `.reg` files.

**For all users :**

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\NonEnum]
"{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}"=dword:00000001
```

**For current user :**

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\NonEnum]
"{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: How did you get that? Process Monitor?

Comment: @Biswapriyo: I knew that it existed, so just a matter of finding the exact string on the Web.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this just removed the network icon from explorer. That's it. Didn't fulfill my need.

Comment: Since this does not hide the mapped shares, I have added some more ideas.